# Devise email confirmation only

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am newbie in rails 
and i start use Devise, - this is a great gem,
but i can't understand how to do only email confirmation? 
on the registration page show only fild for email ... and password send on this email.

I saw  this page:
[https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Email-only-sign-up](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Email-only-sign-up)

but something is wrong..
and i ask is there a detailed guide or video is on this issue or detailed video tutorials specialized on DEVISE

Comment: The tutorial you're following should work. What problems did you have? Did you follow all the instructions there? Can you share some code?

Answer (score 2):

You can find Railscasts on Devise:

- [#209 Introducing Devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise)
- [#210 Customizing Devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise)